# Screw with threads on both ends?

Tags: lighting

I bought some swing arm lamps at an estate sale that came with little knobs to cover the ends of whatever you use to affix the lamps to the wall. These knobs are threaded. What on earth would I use to affix the lamps to the wall on one side that would also allow me to screw on the finishing knobs on the front of the lamps?

Comment: A photo is worth 1000 knobs. Can you add one in?

Comment: Do they have cords to plug in, or are they intended to be wired directly to a wall outlet box?

Comment: Yes, photo, please. Also, I guess you have bought a part of the lamp that came with an arm for affixing to the wall.

Comment: the ones i've seen like that screw onto a bracket, not the wall. The bracket has slots for front-facing machine screws to screw those fancy knobs on, and holes/slots for rear-facing screws that anchor the assembly to the wall. If you don't have those brackets, you'll have to ditch the caps or glue them on to regular screw heads.

Answer (score 4):

Double thread screws, or "hanger bolts". Commonly used for ceiling hooks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get screws with an internal hex head for an allen key or even torx head.

Answer (score 0):

Light fixtures commonly use a cross-brace to attach to an electrical box.

[image: Cross brace]

In the picture above, the vertical piece with slotted holes are used to connect the brace to a 4" or 3.5" electrical box.  The horizontal piece then gets screws threaded into it sticking out of the wall (so the screw head is inside the electrical box.  These "studs" sticking out of the wall then go through the holes in the fixture and the fixture is held in place by little decorative balls or thumbscrews or something.

This article on Fine Homebuilding has some pictures that illustrate that:

https://www.finehomebuilding.com/project-guides/wiring/mounting-light-fixtures

[image: Fine Homebuilding diagram]

Comment: I think this is what dandavis was getting at in the question comments above.  The cross braces come in different styles and are sold in most home improvement stores since they are so common.  They _might not_ line up with the holes in the fixture, because that spacing isn't always standard (though it commonly is).